# Linq Query Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, webforms

I've got a Linq query, oddly though it constantly returns a sequence contains no elements.  The data does exist, I see a count of:

- Manufacturer : One Element
- Person : Three Hundred Fourteen records

The following query returns the error:

```
var people = Query<PersonModel>(getPeople)
     .Where(model => model.FirstName.Contains(search) || 
          model.LastName.Contains(search)) ||
          model.ManufacturerId.Contains(manufacturers.First().ManufacturerId.ToString()))
     .ToList();
```

It was my understanding the `.Where` would filter based on results from a collection.  Why would the error **Contains no elements in sequence.**?

Stack Trace:

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
>   at
>   ...<>c__DisplayClass5.<btnSearch_Click>b__4(...
>   model) in
>   ...aspx.cs:line
>   70    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   ...btnSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in
>   ....aspx.cs:line
>   69    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: That error comes from `First()`

Comment: @SLaks Can you elaborate, I see the result in?  Is it because it hasn't been flattened?

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Check that `manufacturers` has at least one element it it.

Comment: @HashPsi It does, I've validated that it does.  Your correct @SLaks that it comes from `First()` though.

Comment: Could it be that `Query<PersonModel>(getPeople)` somehow clears the content of `manufacturers `?

Comment: I did check that, but it does hold the value still from what I can see.

Comment: You can try adding a break point inside the 'where' clause and check the content of `manufacturers` on the break point.

Comment: Is `manufacturers` a list or some more general enumerable?  If the latter, maybe it has some problem being enumerated more than once, for instance, because it's enumerating through a file?  If so, only the **first** call to `manufacturers.First()` will work, the others will fail.  (I would pull `manufacturers.First()` out of the loop anyway, purely for performance reasons.)

Comment: @dbc It is a `List`.

Comment: I second @dbc's suggestion. Put `manufacturers.First().ManufacturerId.ToString()` into its own variable. Then it will be easier to break at that line.

Comment: IMHO, anytime you use First() especially when basing it on external data, you're asking for errors. I'd reactor to use FirstOrDefault and add a null check. Then fix the logic error of not returning records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var people = Query<PersonModel>(getPeople)
 .Where(model => model.FirstName.Contains(search) || 
      model.LastName.Contains(search) ||
      (manufacturers != null && manufacturers.Any(a => a.ManufacturerId == model.ManufacturerId)))
 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the initial comment about the culprit to the exception being the `First()` is correct.  I was able to circumvent the exception by:

```
 var manufacturers = Build<ManufacturerModel>(getManufacturer)
     .Where(model =>
          model.ManufacturerName.Contains(search));

 if(manufacturers.Any())
      manufacturer = manufacturers.FirstOrDefault().ManufacturerId.ToString();
```

Then I wrapped my initial query in a `if` to test for a value to either attempt to filter on `manufacturer` or not.  The solution works, but isn't ideal a better alternative would be more ideal.

The other example would be:

```
people = Build<PersonModel>(getPeople);
foreach (var person in people)
{
     var m = person.ManufacturerIDs.Split(',')
         .Where(id => (manufacturers != null && manufacturers.Any(item => String.Compare(item.ManufacturerId.ToString(), id, true) == 0))).ToList();

     var r = person.ManufacturerIDs.Split(',')
          .Where(id => (repAgencies != null && repAgencies.Any(item => String.Compare(item.RepAgencyId.ToString(), id, true) == 0))).ToList();

     if (m.Any() || r.Any())
          filter.AddRange(people.Where(model => model.PersonId == person.PersonId).ToList());
}
```

Then when outside that loop, simply do `.Where` on people and add said results into the `filter` list.